# How I can show a loader while setTimeOut() function is processing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Need to show a loader wile `setTimeOut()` function is processing, without using states(react component's state).

When the function is processing the data till then the loader should be displayed on the screen after that the loader should be disappear automatically.

```
 showData = () => {
    if (!this.errorObject.isValid(this.getColHeader())) {
      alert('Please correct the invalid cells and try again...')
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const totalRows = this.hotTableComponent.current.hotInstance.countRows();
      const { data :{ dimensions } } = this.props;
      const nullString = dimensions.reduce((acc, currentValue) => acc + currentValue.delimiter, '');
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus
      for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < totalRows; rowIndex++) {
        const rowData = this.hotTableComponent.current.hotInstance.getDataAtRow(rowIndex)
        rowData.pop();

        const genStr = rowData.reduce((acc, currentValue, index) => {
          const fieldData = dimensions[index].field.data;
          if (fieldData.valueListType === "value" && fieldData.valueType === "undefined") {
            if (fieldData.defaultValue) {
              currentValue = (currentValue) || fieldData.defaultValue;
            }
          } else if (fieldData.valueListType === "codeValue" && currentValue) {
            currentValue = currentValue.slice(currentValue.indexOf('(') + 1, currentValue.length - 1);
          }
          if (currentValue === null) {
            currentValue = ' ';
          }
          return acc + currentValue + dimensions[index].delimiter;
        }, '');

        if (nullString !== genStr) {
            this.updateCell(rowData, rowIndex, genStr);
        }
      }
      }, 100);
    }
  }
```

Comment: create a boolean variable isLoading, make it true in start of function and after everything is done make it false.

Render a component when isLoading is true, that component should show a spinner.

Comment: Why "without using states"? It will be difficult if not impossible to achieve without changing a variable in your component state and using that to conditionally render the loading indicator.

Comment: *"without using states"* - Updating state is exactly how you re-render a component in React.  If you don't want to use React then why are you using React?

Comment: @David  i don't want to use states as i am using handsontable package which have various hooks to validate the different data in the spreadsheet. And when i use state then it will re-load and all validations vanish, which i don't want. And that validation logic trigger on a button's click which combine the data of all rows into single cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you really, and I mean really, don't want to use states you can achieve this by having the loading icon always be rendered but having an opacity of 0. Then before you call `setTimeout` you can use a ref to the loading icon to set it's opacity to 1. Then you can set it to 0 again when the `setTimeout` is executing.

I would not advice going this route though and instead to just use a state to indicate whether or not a component (such as a loading icon) should be shown.